# AS3 inaccessible method - everything is explicitly public

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, compiler-errors

In Flash CS5 I'm getting
1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method testFunc through a reference with static type Doc.
when compiling and can not understand the circumstances, which I have boiled down thoroughly.

MyDoc.as - My document class.

```
package {
   import flash.display.MovieClip;

   public class MyDoc extends MovieClip {
      public function MyDoc() {}

      public function myOtherFunc() : void {}

      public function myFunc() : void {}
   }
}
```

MyClass.as - Linked to a one-frame movie clip with no code containing only a TLF text box.

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class MyClass extends MovieClip {
        public function MyClass( myDoc : MyDoc ) {
            myDoc.myFunc();
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the extent of my FLA - the one movie clip. Empty stage, single frame with no code on it.

What's really confusing me is that I can get an error-free compile if I take the seemingly unrelated TLF text box out of the equation, either by changing it to a classic text box, deleting it, or unlinking its containing MC from MyClass.
I can also get rid of the error by removing myOtherFunc()'s definition or moving it below myFunc()'s, which I had to do a few times just to convince myself that it was true.

Any ideas as to what is going on?

Update: I just confirmed the same behavior on a friend's version of CS5. He's using a Mac as opposed to my Windows setup, and he only has the CS5 version installed, whereas I have both CS5 and CS4. This really seems like it might be a Flash bug...

Comment: First off the constructor shouldn't have a return type. Try renaming your doc class. Maybe it gets overridden by the TLF due to a name conflict?

Comment: For some reason I always thought declaring the return type : void was tantamount to omitting the return type, but that doesn't really make sense I guess. Interestingly, that suggestion fixed the example but not the code from which it was derived, so I've removed the constructor return type declarations and re-boiled it down and edited my question. I've also renamed Doc, but that didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to include the textLayout.swc in your source path http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/textlayout.html

Note: Successful answer is in comments

Comment: After taking Roy's advice and re-boiling the code down, it really does seem to be something with that TLF field. I've never touched the SWC source path stuff, so I assume it's on the default values. The directory appears to point to an existing SWC file, assuming $(AppConfig) is pointing to where my research indicates it should be, C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Common\Configuration. I can't figure out how to verify this - I'm worried it might be confused because I have both CS4 and CS5 installed? Also, here is what my AS3 settings look like:
http://cl.ly/1V3z2a3r2K1o2O1L2W1S

Comment: There seems to be a number of issues with the TLF. I haven't had any direct experience with it, but one suggestion that keeps coming up is to merge the swc into your swf by changing the "Default Linkage" to "Merged into code" http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSb03e830bd6f770ee-4b0db644124bbdb363d-8000.html#WSb03e830bd6f770ee72b69dc71257a25aa72-8000 ... I'm not sure if this is relevant to your issue, or even a desirable solution, but it might be worth a quick try.